# Codeigniter - Edit user as admin

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Working user manage page with codeigniter, I made edit user function my self and that works but notification can't working. Mean If problem in updating user detail that should through error or Success but nothing happening but datas are updating.

Here is Model(Admin_model.php):

```
public function editUser($id, $data)
{

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
}
```

controller(Admin.php):

```
public function edit_user($id) 
{

    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {

        $this->load->view('default/admin/edit_user');

    } else {

        $data = array(
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname'  => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-j H:i:s')
        );

        if($this->Admin_model->editUser($id,$data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('global_alert','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">User updated!</div>');
            redirect('admin/users');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('default/admin/edit_user');

            $this->session->set_flashdata('global_alert','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Something wrong!</div>');
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How you are showing the flash message in your view file?

Comment: Yes, i am using flash message view file header.

Comment: Flash data is stored and used for the next session call. So your error message in flash data will not be available for your view. If you refresh the page it will appear. Your success message is fine as you set the flash data and then redirect, which is correct. If you are not redirecting, set your error message as a normal variable to send to your view.

Comment: i have fixed that by using @pgee70 answer, which is below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$this->Admin_model->editUser is not returning anything.  try

```
public function editUser($id, $data)
{

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->update('users', $data);
    if ($result === FALSE)
    {
        show_error('error !');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: it probably wont fail.  but you could trigger an error  in editUser if $this->db->update === FALSE and then return the value.

Comment: Thank you it helps